# MySql: delete from multiple tables using left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have this tables:

1. Orders: OrderId, UserId
2. OrderItems: OrderId, Price

There is foreign key on OrderItems.OrderId and it's possible to have order without order items. I want to delete all orders and order ietms for some user. This sql with inner join works fine:

```
DELETE o, oi 
FROM Orders o 
JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId 
WHERE o.UserId = 11
```

but it doesn't delete orders without order items (inner join). But sql query with left join

```
DELETE o, oi 
FROM Orders o 
LEFT JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId 
WHERE o.UserId = 11
```

throws error

> cannot update or delete parent row.

What's wrong? is it possible to delete all orders (with items and without) for user in one query?

Comment: Thats weird since the WHERE in the LEFT JOIN will make it an INNER JOIN anyway.Change you WHERE to AND in your second query to get all orders.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN in DELETE query is anyway strange!

Comment: @Mihail , no. this condition "ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId AND o.UserId = 11" selects orders with items only.

Comment: Post it as your own answer and accept it to solve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) is explained that

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might process tables in an order that differs from that of their parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables to be modified accordingly

So I'll just use sequent deletion.